# How to Integrate facebook invite in react js mobile site

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, redux

I am working on a react redux application.
Want the functionality to send the site(mobile site ) facebook invite to my friends.
What is the way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different in which we can embed facebook send button

- Use simple web redirection url

  http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=320949351409311&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&link=http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html&redirect_uri=https://www.domain.com/
- to use inbuilt facebook send button in react js
  Please refer : https://gist.github.com/andrewimm/9fdd0007c3476446986a9f600ba4183f

It includes an facebook send button iframe. It is easy to use but you can not configure send button.

- To implement send button functionality on your button,use its javascript sdk

```html
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // assume we are already logged in
      FB.init({appId: '123050457758183', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/'
          });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

or in react we can simply load the scripts in functions like

```js
loadScript(){
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_US/all.js';

        document.body.appendChild(script);
        var code = document.createElement('script');
        code.text="FB.init({appId:'APP_ID',cookie:true,status:true,xfbml:true});";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.body.appendChild(code);
        }, 0)
    }();
```

and then send invite on click

```js
 FacebookInviteFriends(){

        FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            link: 'https://m.olx.in'
        });
    }
```

```html
 <div onClick={this.FacebookInviteFriends.bind(this)}></div>
```